# Sharepoint Server 2010 development environment setup error

Tags: windows-7, sharepoint-2010

****Tears hair out****

I've been following this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx walkthrough to set up Sharepoint **Server** 2010 on my local machine (Windows 7 64-bit). Sharepoint "installs" absolutely fine but the "configuration" program will not run. I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Stand-alone provisioning has failed because an 
error occurred while enumerating the SharePoint Server products installed on this 
server.
```

The only "help" I can find is here - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/42239d23-26cd-4571-a4ac-b3bc74f9ad3a/ - but I've **already put in and validated a license key** so surely that can't be the problem?

I've included full exception details below in case it helps. If anybody could shed light on this I'd be grateful.

**Note:** I want Sharepoint **Server** rather than **Foundation** on my local machine so that it replicates the live environment, obviously. Sharepoint **Foundation** does install without any problems.

**Also note:** Any HTTP requests from my machine are routed through a proxy.

HELP!
(Thanks).

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Stand-alone provisioning has failed because an error occurred while enumerating the SharePoint Server products installed on this server.
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.EvaluatorModeProvisioning.OfficeServerProducts.get_OfficeProductList()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.EvaluatorModeProvisioning.OfficeServerProducts.IsInstalled(OfficeServerProductToProvision product)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.EvaluatorModeProvisioning.SharedEvaluatorModeProvisioning.GetProvisioner()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.EvaluatorModeProvisioning.SharedEvaluatorModeProvisioning..ctor(TraceListener listener)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeConstructor(Object[] args, SignatureStruct& signature, IntPtr declaringType)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ReflectionHelper.InvokeConstructor(String assemblyQualifiedName, Type[] constructorSignature, Object[] constructorParameters)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskCommon.ReflectionHelperInvokeConstructor(String assemblyQualifiedName, Type[] constructorSignature, Object[] constructorParameters, TaskBase task)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.EvalModeProvisionTask.LoadProvisioner()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.WelcomeForm.ShowNextFormForServerRoleSingleServer()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.WelcomeForm.PsconfigBaseFormNextButtonClickedEventHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

**EDIT** - have tried with a completely fresh install / license and same error. I have Office 2003 on my machine - could this be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer it myself then (with the help of a chap call Rock Wang...)

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/baaded7c-8782-47f6-ba75-0bdd98aa3706

How a corrupted install of SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 can bring down an entire Sharepoint site collection is beyond me / a little worrying though... :)